# Как настроить angular-gridster.js, чтобы избежать наложения изображений и их ресайза

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как настроить [angular-gridster](http://manifestwebdesign.github.io/angular-gridster/), чтобы убрать Z-слои и наложение изображений друг на друга? Сейчас, если изображения большие, они накладываются друг на друга.

Настройки, видимо, находятся в `$scope.gridOpts`. И еще не срабатывает `resizable: { enabled : false }`, все равно можно растягивать изображения.

Есть официальный [демо-пример](https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/main), там ресайз каким-то образом отключается.

Мои текущие настройки:

```
$scope.gridsterOpts = {
    margins: [20, 20],
    outerMargin: false,
    floating: true,
    pushing: true,
    draggable: { 
       enabled: true 
    },
    resizable: { 
       enabled: false,
       handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'se', 'sw'] 
    }
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы изображения не накладывались друг на друга, т.е. учитывался их реальный размер, и они просто располагались рядом; чтобы не было возможности ресайза при помощи растягивания изображений за угол. И была возможность перемещения. Сейчас изображения перемещаются нормально, но накладываются друг на друга, и все равно доступен ресайз.

**Обновление:**
После добавления к html-блоку div, в котором находятся все изображения, опции `<div gridster="gridsterOpts">` ресайз выключился. **Осталась проблема наложения друг на друга изображений.**

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса, не могу обнаружить описываемой проблемы: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09f0gpwa/embedded/result/)

Comment: `<div gridster="gridsterOpts" ng-init="selected = {}">
        <ul>
            <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in standardItems" ng-click="selected.item = item" ng-style="{ 'z-index': selected.item === item ? 999 : '' }"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>`

Comment: Просто перезагрузите z-index элемента gridster, когда виджеты не находятся в состоянии перетаскивания: `.gridster-item:not(.gridster-item-moving) {
    //drop z-index to make it possible to set higher than 2 z-index for widget elements
    z-index: initial;
  }`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Ответ [@VanyaAvchyan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207445/vanya-avchyan)

*configuration*

```
$scope.gridsterOpts = {
    margins: [20, 20],
    outerMargin: false,
    floating: true,
    pushing: true,
    draggable: { 
       enabled: true 
    },
    resizable: { 
       enabled: false,
       handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'se', 'sw'] 
    }
}
```

*view*

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts" ng-init="selected = {}">
  <ul>
    <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in standardItems" ng-click="selected.item = item" ng-style="{ 'z-index': selected.item === item ? 999 : '' }"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*styles*

```
.gridster-item:not(.gridster-item-moving) {
  z-index: initial; /* drop z-index to make it possible to set higher than 2 z-index for widget elements */
}
```